# Assign derived class unique_ptr to base class unique_ptr

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, unique-ptr

I created a custom istream derived from std::istream that uses a custom streambuf when the file is a zipped file and std::filebuf otherwise.

```
#mystream.h
class my_stream: public istream {
  public:
     explicit my_stream(const std::string &path);
  private:       
     std::unique_ptr<std::streambuf> b_;
}

#mystream.cpp
my_stream::my_stream(const std::string &path) :std::istream(nullptr) {
    if(path.substr(path.length()-6, path.length())==".gzip"){
        b_ = std::make_unique<gzipbuf>(path); //gzipbuf is derived from std::streambuf
    } 
    else {
        std::unique_ptr<std::filebuf> fb;
        fb->open(path.c_str(), std::ios::in);
        b_ = fb;
    }
    this->init(b_.get());
}
```

I am able to assign derived class unique_ptr to base class unique_ptr at one place

```
b_ = std::make_unique<gzipbuf>(path);
```

but not at the other

```
b_ = fb;
```

It says

```
candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'unique_ptr<std::filebuf, default_delete<std::basic_filebuf<char>>>' to 'unique_ptr<std::basic_streambuf<char>, default_delete<std::basic_streambuf<char>>>' for 1st argument
      operator=(unique_ptr&& __u) noexcept
```

Comment: You need to *move* it: `b = std::move(fb);` because here can only ever be one (no copies).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, after this line

```
std::unique_ptr<std::filebuf> fb;
```

`fb` doesn't actually point at anything, it is just an empty `unique_ptr` so you are invoking undefined behaviour here:

```
fb->open(path.c_str(), std::ios::in);
```

To fix this just change the line to:

```
auto fb = std::make_unique<std::filebuf>();
```

Regarding the error you are getting, if this line were allowed

```
b_ = fb;
```

then afterwards both `b_` and `fb` would point at the same object. This is not allowed by `unique_ptr`. A resource can be owned by one, and only one, `unique_ptr`. One solution is to pass ownership from `fb` to `b_` using `std::move`:

```
b_ = std::move(fb)
```

and then `fb` no longer owns anything.

Personally, I like to initialize member variables in the constructor initializer list wherever possible and would extract out the creation of the `streambuf` to a separate function in order to do so:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::streambuf> createStream(const std::string &path) {
    if(path.substr(path.length()-5, path.length())==".gzip"){  // I think you meant 5 here!
        return std::make_unique<gzipbuf>(path); 
    }
    auto fb = std::make_unique<std::filebuf>();
    fb->open(path.c_str(), std::ios::in);
    return fb;
}
```

Then the constructor of `my_stream` can be:

```
my_stream::my_stream(const std::string &path) : std::istream(nullptr),
  b_(createStream(path)) {
    this->init(b_.get());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me, but it was because I forgot to inherit publicly :)

```cpp
// Was:
class Derived: Base
{
};

// Should have been:
class Derived: public Base
{
};
```